# how to implement a operator use in hierarchy?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, operator-overloading

I have a `Base` class with several derived classes:

```
class Base {
private:
    long id;
public:
    Base() {}
    ~Base() {}
    Base &operator = (long temp) {
        id = temp;
        return *this;
    }
};

template <class C>
class Temp1 : public Base {
public:
    Temp1() {}
    ~Temp1() {}
    //do something;
};

template <class C>
class Temp2 : public Base {
public:
    Temp2() {}
    ~ Temp2() {}
    //do something;
};

class Executor1 : public Temp1<int> {
public:
    Executor1() {}
    ~Executor1() {}
};

class Executor2 : public Temp2<char> {
public:
    Executor2() {}
    ~Executor2() {}
};
```

I want those classes to support `operator =`.
e.g:

```
int main()
{
    long id1 = 0x00001111, id2 = 0x00002222;
    Executor1 exec1;
    Executor2 exec2;

    exec1 = id1;  //exec2.id = id1;
    exec2 = id2;  //exec2.id = id2;
}
```

I define `operator =` in `Base` whose declaration is `Base &operator = (long);`.

But there is a problem clearly that `=` doesn't work to derive classes. So I have to define `operator =` totally do the same thing to every `Executor`.

How to deal with this case in `Base` in a better way?

Comment: I would recommend against defining an `operator=` that takes an unrelated type.

Comment: Better. Though all those missing semicolons are also one of the things I was talking about. I fixed it for you myself though.

Comment: Write a function `from_int` or define an *explicit* constructor. `operator=` like you want to define is highly confusing and needs some serious justification.

Comment: Unrelated, but an hierarchy without any virtual functions is highly dubious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pull the =-operator into the scope of the class:

```
class Base
{
public:
    long id;

    Base& operator=(long id)
    {
        this->id = id;
        return *this;
    }
};

class Temp2
    : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::operator=;
};
```

You have to pull the operator= into the scope because the implicitly generated copy operator= of Temp2 was hiding the operator= of Base. Got this hint from @Angew from's comment.

Comment: I have try. but the program `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` while I run it

Comment: @umbreLLaJYL - The segmentation fault is due to a bug in your program. In code you don't show here. This answers the question you *asked*. If you have a new unrelated question about your seg fault, you can post another question with another [mcve].

Comment: @umbreLLaJYL it seems to work fine, you might ask another question with this specific issue. When you write this new question, please provide directly a [MCVE].

Comment: @StoryTeller I mean that the program runs well. it crash after I add that line.

Comment: @umbreLLaJYL - I understood what you meant. Your program has a bug. It's not this line that introduced it, though it likely uncovered it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Isn't the operator= calling the copy consturcotr if the operator= isn't user defined? And as second point: If the operator= isn't considered as constructor I guess it shouldn't be necessary to pull the operator explicitly into scope. That's why I was thinking you have to pull the operator into the scope of the class like you do in constructor inheriting, like they do here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

Comment: @JulianH not it isn't, when the operator is called here: `exec1 = id1;` the `exec1` object has already been constructed. The constructor is called here: `Executor1 exec1;`

Comment: @JulianH No, it's most definitely not calling the copy ctor. It's just that the class has the implicitly-defined `operator=`, which hides the inherited `operator=`. That is why it has to be brought into scope.

Comment: @StoryTeller it do have a bug in my code! thanks to everyone!

Comment: @Angew this does make more sense to me, thank you. I was wrong.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I read that. its my mistake. the answer have deal with my case. thanks to all!

Comment: @umbreLLaJYL OK, I misunderstood your comment due to your poor english.

Comment: that's so embarrassed.

Comment: @umbreLLaJYL no problem.